# Check if string contains set of other string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

I want to check if string one in array contain the letters from words in string 2. Here's my example array:

`(["Floor", "far"]);`

function should return false because "a" is not in string "Floor" 
But for array like this:

`(["Newbie", "web"]);`

It should return true because all of letters from "web" are in "Newbie".

Here's my code so far...

```
function mutation(arr) {
    var newArr = [];
    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        newArr.push(arr[i].toLowerCase().split(""));
    }
    for (i=0; i<newArr.length; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<newArr[i].length; j++) {
            console.log(newArr[0][j]+ (newArr[1][j]));
    }
  }
}
mutation(["Newbie", "web"]);
```

I know that it won't work and I'm out of ideas how to make it. I try to make a set of all letters in two array and compare them. If there is at least one *false* the function should return false. Should I nest *indexOf()* method somewhere?

Comment: Using sets should work. I Googled for a library and found JS.set. If you put all letters from 'Newbie' into set1 and 'web' to set 2, then your result is simply set2.isSubsetOf(set1).

Comment: Alternatively, check for every letter in 'web' has indexOf > -1 in 'newbie'.

Comment: OK. But how to make it working using indexOf() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work for you. Break up the string of letters to check for into an array. Iterate over the array getting each letter and checking if the string passed in contains the letter, setting our result to false if it doesn't.

```
function mutation(arr) {
  var charArr = arr[1].toLowerCase().split("");
  var result = true;
  charArr.forEach(element => {
    if (!arr[0].toLowerCase().includes(element)) {
      result = false;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
console.log(mutation(["Newbie", "web"]));
```

Comment: Looks good. But how to achieve the same using indexOf() method or test() ? I'm new into JS and don't know yet about these methods You used here.

Comment: In the body of `charArr.forEach` you would do something like `if (arr[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(element) === -1)` As for the test method, I wouldn't personally use it here, but I'm sure you could find an example somewhere online

Comment: @icelandico `includes` is just a good way of doing `indexOf(...) !== -1`

Answer (score 1):

The cool way would be:

```
 const mutation =([one, two]) => (set => [...two.toLowerCase()].every(char =>  set.has(char)))(new Set(one.toLowerCase()));
```

How it works:

At first we destructure the passed array into the first and the second word:

```
 [one, two]
```

Now that we got both, we build up a Set of characters from the first word:

```
 (set => /*...*/)(new Set(one))
```

All that in an IIFE cause we need the set here:

```
 [...two].every(char => set.has(char))
```

That spreads the second word in an array, so we got an array of chars and then checks if all characters are part of the set we built up from the other word.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that one word, which might have several repeating letters, is contained in another, use [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to count the letters, and store create a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of letter -> counts. Do that for both words. Check if all [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) of 2nd word are contained in the 1st word map using [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const countLetters = (w) => 
  w.toLowerCase()
  .split('')
  .reduce((r, l) => r.set(l, (r.get(l) || 0) + 1), new Map());

const mutation = ([a, b]) => {
  const al = countLetters(a);
  const bl = countLetters(b);
  
  return [...bl].every(([k, v]) => v <= (al.get(k) || 0));
};

console.log(mutation(["Floor", "far"])); // false

console.log(mutation(["Floor", "for"])); // true

console.log(mutation(["Floor", "foroo"])); // false

console.log(mutation(["Newbie", "web"])); // true
```